# Wants a Smooth Right-to-Left Opening Transition for Modals in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I want to create a model like a drawer, so I want a transition anchor from right to left with some slowly transitioning like all ease 1s at the time of clicking the button, and when it closes, it should be close with a transition with all ease 1s, but here I have tried to apply the transition property but it's not working, so how can I achieve that model look like opening from the right end slowly and closing towards the right slowly?

```
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [showDetailsModal, setShowDetailsModal] = useState(false);
  const customStylesProject = {
    content: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "0%",
      left: "70%",
      opacity: showDetailsModal ? 1 : 0, 
      right: "0%",
      bottom: "5%",
      overflow: "hidden",
      width: "206px",
      height: "100vh",
      backgroundColor: "skyblue",
      transition: "all ease 1s",
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal
        isOpen={showDetailsModal}
        className="modal-dialog"
        style={customStylesProject}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setShowDetailsModal(false);
        }}
      >
        <div className={`modal-container page-modal-size1 ${
    showDetailsModal ? "modal-transition" : ""
  }`}>
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h2 className="title">{`Info Details`}</h2>
          </div>
          
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button
              className="cancel-button-common cancel-button-layout-style-project mr-3 fontPoppinsRegularMd"
              onClick={() => setShowDetailsModal(false)}
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <button onClick={() => setShowDetailsModal(true)}>Click</button>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```